Can't unalias then redefine as a function in the same conditional
Here is a simplified implementation of an issue in my bash/zsh aliases file:
alias foobar='echo bar'   # this is out of my control
if true; then
  unalias foobar
  echo we got inside the conditional
  foobar() { echo foo; }
fi
foobar

To be clear nothing else is going on, I ran fresh shells without a $HOME 
(quotes converted from ​`…' to '…' to fix the syntax highlighting)
$ HOME=/ zsh
tabasco% set -x
tabasco% source test.sh
+zsh:2> source test.sh
+test.sh:1> alias 'foobar=echo bar'
test.sh:4: defining function based on alias 'foobar'
test.sh:4: parse error near '()'
tabasco% exit

$ HOME=/ bash
adamhotep@tabasco:/tmp$ set -x
adamhotep@tabasco:/tmp$ source test.sh
+ source test.sh
++ alias 'foobar=echo bar'
bash: test.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token '('
bash: test.sh: line 4: '  foobar() { echo foo; }'
adamhotep@tabasco:/tmp$ exit

As you can see, the shell doesn't even test the condition (true), nor does it get to the echo statement. An answer to a related question suggests function foobar { echo foo; }, which (if I understand correctly) functions as an alias and overrides a preexisting alias. That has worked for me in the past, but not this time.
The conditional is doing something odd. Simplifying it didn't help, but duplicating it did:
alias foobar='echo bar'   # this is out of my control
if true; then
  unalias foobar
fi
if true; then
  echo we got inside the conditional
  foobar() { echo foo; }
fi
foobar

What's going on here? I assume it has something to do with processing order and that it's looking ahead and getting prematurely stuck, but I would like to learn more about how this and similar unexpected ordering issues are triggered, and how to better remedy them.

There is a number of issues here, all having to do with understanding the fundamentals of shell command language. Some of the highlights: 1) true is a utility, 2) aliases and functions are distinct concepts and don't mix, 3) if ...; then ...; fi construct deals with utilities and their exit statuses. Manual pages for the corresponding shells describe this in detail.

@Vilinkameni – Both bash and zsh implement true as a builtin. if conditions are overwhelmingly used with [ or [[, which bash and zsh also implement as builtins. I'm not trying to mix aliases and functions, I'm trying to replace an alias with a function after undefining it to avoid that exact issue. The manual pages –and the Posix spec– describe if as dealing with commands, which refers to utilities, builtins, aliases, functions, etc.

(Correction: [[ is a keyword rather than a builtin as noted in Why is [ a shell builtin and [[ a shell keyword?. This doesn't matter in the context of this question, but I worry we're getting unnecessarily pedantic here, so I wanted to head that off.)

"Bash always reads at least one complete line of input, and all lines that make up a compound command, before executing any of the commands on that line or the compound command. Aliases are expanded when a command is read, not when it is executed."

The true manual page describes true as a utility. The Shell Command Language section doesn't list true as a Special Builtin Utility, so it is a utility. Note that POSIX states "An implementation may choose to make any utility a built-in". On OpenBSD there is a /usr/bin/true executable, for example.

@Vilinkameni – Correct, but if you run type true in either bash, zsh, or even dash, you'll see it is indeed a builtin. I don't know of a modern Posix shell build that doesn't do that. More to the point, this has nothing to do with this question. I chose true as the simplest test to illustrate that the test doesn't matter. Replace it with echo yes (also a builtin, also not required to be a builtin by the Posix standard) or with date (definitely a utility), it'll still exhibit the same issue.

Thank you @muru (presumably you're the one who marked this question a duplicate), that does explain the issue. I wasn't able to find that when I searched for duplicates before making this question due to my thinking about unaliasing.

Note that even though true may be implemented as a built-in (which is allowed by POSIX), it doesn't need to be. Anyway, it has to do with the question. The wording in the question is the shell doesn't even test the condition (true). The Conditional Construct if doesn't "test the condition", that is what the test utility (often symlinked to /bin/[) does. The if construct uses the exit status of a compound-list to determine whether to execute another compound-list.

@Vilinkameni – The Posix spec for if specifies if compound-list; then compound-list; fi, implying that the lists are distinct. That was my confusion. As the other question's answer notes, the shell evaluates the whole stanza before updating the aliases. Again, this has nothing to do with builtins vs utilities. You seem stuck on semantics rather than my question. I am not, in fact, implementing my own Posix shell.

Having a clear grasp of the terms involved in the issue often leads directly to the solution.

Sure, but not this time.
